# SQL Merging data to get timeline

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I need to combine 2 sets of data from different systems. One from a Door fob security system and one from the HR holiday system.

End goal is create an accurate timeline of how long people are in the building - the difficulty i'm facing is half days.

So an Employee enters the building at 08:25 and leaves at 12:45. The HR system shows a half day 12:00 till 16:00 (the hours wont always stack on as the HR system is limited to larger intervals).

> The 1st result would be 08:25 start and 16:00 finish (1st Oct)
>
> The 2nd result would be 08:00 start and 16:12 finish (2nd Oct)

.. but holidays can be AM and PM. So it may be the other way round. I've struggled with different `MAX` and `MINS` and trying to `RANK` or `CASE WHEN` but cant get the figures right both ways consistently.

Here is a crude example of the data

```
SELECT 123456 AS EmployeeID
        , 'John Jones' AS EmployeeName
        , '01-Oct-2018' AS DateEvent
        , '08:25:00' AS EnterTime
        , '12:45:00' AS LeaveTime
        , 'DOOR' AS EventType
UNION ALL
SELECT 123456 AS EmployeeID
        , 'John Jones' AS EmployeeName
        , '01-Oct-2018' AS DateEvent
        , '12:00:00' AS StartTime
        , '16:00:00' AS EndTime
        , 'HOL' AS EventType
UNION ALL
SELECT 123456 AS EmployeeID
        , 'John Jones' AS EmployeeName
        , '02-Oct-2018' AS DateEvent
        , '12:30:00' AS EnterTime
        , '16:12:00' AS LeaveTime
        , 'DOOR' AS EventType
UNION ALL
SELECT 123456 AS EmployeeID
        , 'John Jones' AS EmployeeName
        , '02-Oct-2018' AS DateEvent
        , '08:00:00' AS StartTime
        , '12:00:00' AS EndTime
        , 'HLL' AS EventType
```

Comment: what how is the expected result looks like ?

Comment: @Squirrel - it would be the first and last entry of whichever was first an last. So for the 1st October example it would use the door log for the first and the holiday system for the last. then vice versa for the 2nd.... if that makes sense.

Comment: can you show us how do you want the result to looks like ?

Comment: edited it to highlight the desired result and made simpler...

Comment: Please share your table structure and expected output as it will be more visualize than the text requirement what is in the current.

Comment: @SurajKumar - table structure is the exact same as the query provided -  run the query you will have the exact same output that I have..

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to the below query

```
select * into #tempEvent from(
SELECT 123456 AS EmployeeID
        , 'John Jones' AS EmployeeName
        , '01-Oct-2018' AS DateEvent
        , '08:25:00' AS EnterTime
        , '12:45:00' AS LeaveTime
        , 'DOOR' AS EventType
UNION ALL
SELECT 123456 AS EmployeeID
        , 'John Jones' AS EmployeeName
        , '01-Oct-2018' AS DateEvent
        , '12:00:00' AS StartTime
        , '16:00:00' AS EndTime
        , 'HOL' AS EventType
UNION ALL
SELECT 123456 AS EmployeeID
        , 'John Jones' AS EmployeeName
        , '02-Oct-2018' AS DateEvent
        , '12:30:00' AS EnterTime
        , '16:12:00' AS LeaveTime
        , 'DOOR' AS EventType
UNION ALL
SELECT 123456 AS EmployeeID
        , 'John Jones' AS EmployeeName
        , '02-Oct-2018' AS DateEvent
        , '08:00:00' AS StartTime
        , '12:00:00' AS EndTime
        , 'HLL' AS EventType
)event

select * from #tempEvent

select EmployeeID,  EmployeeName, dateevent, min(entertime) as start, max(leavetime) as finish 
from #tempEvent
group by EmployeeID,    EmployeeName, dateevent
```

The output is as shown below

```
EmployeeID  EmployeeName    dateevent   start       finish
123456      John Jones      01-Oct-2018 08:25:00    16:00:00
123456      John Jones      02-Oct-2018 08:00:00    16:12:00
```